# Remove Old Grub Loader From Second Drive Without Linux (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, grub

I have two drives. One small SSD which windows 7 is installed on. One terrabyte hard drive from ages ago. It has all my data and steam games. I just got a new motherboard and CPU so I reinstalled windows on the SSD. Replugged in my larger games drive and now GRUB loader comes up.

Sometime about 5 years ago I dual booted linux for about a week off that larger drive. So somehow GRUB lingered through and didn't rear its head until now.

I've tried booting with the windows disk, using the recovery prompt and running `bootrec/fixmbr` and `bootrec/fixboot` but these do no not work. I've tried running `bootrec/rebuildbcd` but it says it doesn't find any installations of windows which from what I gather means there's a BCD already.

How do I nuke GRUB from my second drive so it allows me to boot to windows like normal without wiping the second drive so I wont lose all my games, saves, and code? Preferably without a linux installation, though push come to shove I could use a live CD.

Edit 1:

Attempting to use the bios to ignore the GRUB drive.

So there's this screen in the bios.
[image]

It doesn't show the the HDD in the boot option priorities. SanDisk is my SSD.

[image]

Under Hard Disk BBS Priorities I removed the HDD.

Now when I boot. I get `Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key.`

When I change Boot mode select from "LEGACY+UEFI" to just "UEFI" and boot I get a EFI shell which I unfortunately couldn't get a screenshot of. So here's the shaky cam. 
[image]

Comment: Did you make sure that the SSD is your first boot drive in the BIOS? You should be able to boot into Windows with the way you set up your system. Once you are inside Windows removing the old Linux partition from the old 1 TB HDD is simple using the Disk Management tool.

Comment: @Ayan, I've updated the question with some information.

Comment: @Tocs , Are you able to boot into windows 7, if so, then post a screenshot of Disk Management Tool. Let's see which disk/partition has the `active` flag.